# Infinite loop error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load an remote web page to the specific div tag using jquery but the page going in infinite loop. please tell me a soluion about that. Following is the code i have used for that.

```
<div id="data" style="display:none"></div>  
         <div id="data1" style="display:none"></div>  
          <div id="data2" style="display:none"></div>  
<form name="frm" id="frm" method="post" action="">
        <select id="Make" name="Make" onchange="test1(this.value)">
        <option value="">Choose Make</option>
        </select>
        <select id="year" name="year" onchange="test2(this.value)">
        <option value="">Choose Year</option>
        </select>
        <select id="model" name="model" onchange="">
        <option value="">Choose Year</option>
        </select>
        </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test()
    {
        $.get("/SearchResults.asp?Cat=1833", function (data)
         {
         //alert("test1");
                    $('#data').html(data);

         });
                getVa();

    }
    test();


    function test1(val) 
    {
        $.get(val, function (data) 
        {
                 //alert("test2");
                   $('#data1').html(data);
        });
                getVa();

    }


    function test2(val) 
    {
        $.get(val, function (data) 
        {
                // alert("test3");
                   $('#data2').html(data);
        });
                getVa();

    }

    function getVa()
    {
    var lnk =new Array();
    var cnt=0;
    var val=new Array
    $("a").each(function(index){
    if($(this).attr("class")=="subcategory_link")
    {


    //document.getElementsById("year").innerHTML="<option value="+$(this).attr("href")+">test</option>";
    lnk[cnt]=$(this).attr("href");
    cnt=cnt+1;
      //alert($(this).attr("href"));

    }
    });
    cnt=0;
    $("span").each(function(ind){
    if($(this).attr("class")=="subcategory_name")
    {
      val[cnt]=$(this).text();
      cnt=cnt+1;
    }
    });


    var select = document.getElementById("Make");
    var select1 = document.getElementById("year");
    var select2 = document.getElementById("model");


    if(select.options.length<=1)
    {

    for(i=0; i<lnk.length;i++)
    {
    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(val[i], lnk[i]);
      //alert(lnk[i]);
      //alert(val[i]);
    }
    }
    else if(select1.options.length<=1)
    {
    select1.options[select1.options.length] = new Option(val[i], lnk[i]);
    }
    else if(select2.options.length<=1)
    {
    select2.options[select2.options.length] = new Option(val[i], lnk[i]);
    }

    }
    </script>
```

URL: http://tinyurl.com/7zml6yn

Comment: That is a lot of code for us to troubleshoot. Maybe you could narrow down the problem by removing any code that does not cause the error. Just keep trimming and testing until the error no longer exists, then put back the last thing you removed.

Comment: is "new Option()" valid javascript/jquery?

Comment: As a side note - your `cnt` is not necessary since that first argument in the `.each` function provies the index as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the same page (i.e. the html you have shown us above is searchresults.asp), then you are going to parse the page and run the scripts when you load the html, which will call test again etc...